# C# NAudio: What is correct data struct?

Tags: c#, naudio

I have a circuit that sends me microphone data as bytes.I save these bytes into .txt file and reading them using `FileStream` Circuit's frequency is 16khz. 
My problem is when I try to convert those bytes to wav, it gives me a meaningless result. Also my record time is not matched with wav file duration.

```
WaveFormat waveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000,8,1);
using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(tempFile, waveFormat))
{
  writer.Write(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.Length);
}
```

What is the data structure for a wav file? Should I convert them Hex or float or something else?

Comment: What circuit?  Do you have a part number or similar so we can investigate the format it uses?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have enough information and knowledge about the circuit. I only know that it sends me bytes via bluetooh and it is work with an ST32M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very common to record 16 bit rather than 8 bit, so I'd recommend trying this first:

```
new WaveFormat(16000,16,1);
```

Once you get the bit depth right, you should hear recognizable sound, although the pitch will be wrong if you have the wrong sample rate or channel count.

Comment: I have tried that but still it is not recognizable sound and still it is not match with my record time. There might be something wrong with my data. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: one other thing to try is whether it is big endian or little endian (swap every pair of bytes). Also, there is the possibility that the audio is compressed in some way.

Comment: I have changed hertz as 1600 and now wav duration is match with my record time. In the light of this information can I decide that the hertz is 1600? I will try it is big endian or little endain. Thank you again.

Comment: that would be an extremely low sample rate. probably the audio is compressed in some way.

Comment: Hi.I need to ask a question. I set `int channels` to 1 but when I read the wav file using `NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(open.FileName));` this code it says Channels = 2. Can you explain why Channels are equal to 2 ? @Mark Heath